# Kendo autocomplete showing [object object] instead of propery value

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-autocomplete

I'm trying to configure kendo autocomplete using their tutorial.
The problem is that autocomplete control display objects instead of property value which I set in kendo initialization (see capture):

```
@(
    Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()
    .Name("products")
    .Placeholder("Find Product...")
    .DataTextField("Name")
    .Template("<span><img src='/Content/Images/default-photo.jpg' " +
    "width='20' height='20' />&nbsp;${data}</span>")
    .DataSource(source =>
    {
        source.Read(read =>
        {
            read.Action("GetProducts", "Search")
            .Data("onAdditionalData");
        })
            .ServerFiltering(true);
    })

)

<script>
    function onAdditionalData() {
        return {
            text: $("#products").val()
        };
    }
</script>
```

[image]

After I click this item the name is showing properly:
[image]

My action return type is `return Json(products, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`
where products is `ICollection<VmProduct>`
Whats going on?

Comment: The return type of `onAdditionalData`is an object with a protperty named `text`. try to return directly `$("#products").val()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set the `DataTextField` but you're overwriting it when you set the `Template`, because kendo will execute the template instead of getting the field you set. But that's not the problem, the problem is that in your template you're printing the `data` object, which is.. an object actually. You need to print it's property related to the suggestion text, e.g.:

```
.Template("<span><img src='/Content/Images/default-photo.jpg' " +
"width='20' height='20' />&nbsp;${data.Name}</span>")
```

Give it a try and tell us what happens.

Comment: You saves my life! Thank you a lot!

Comment: @user3818229 np, glad to help! Remember to mark as an answer.